# Showing that $x$ is in the span of $v_1, v_2$ if $(x - x_0) \cdot n = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $x_0 \in \Bbb R^n\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$  and $x_0 \cdot n = 0$. Suppose also $(x - x_0) \cdot n = 0$. How can I show that $x\in\operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2\}$? It is intuitively clear of course, but I can't hit upon a formal proof.

Comment: Are you assuming that $n$ is a normal vector to the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$? Otherwise it isn't true in general: e.g. in $\mathbb{R}^3$, let $x_0, n$ be $e_1$ and $e_2$, respectively. So they are in the $xy$-plane and at right angles to each other. Now let $x = e_3 + x_0$, so that $x - x_0 = e_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this statement is true? Consider the collection of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by $$v_1=e_1, v_2=e_2, x_0=e_1+2e_2, n=e_3, x=e_4$$ then all of conditions in the hypothesis are true but $x$ doesn't belong to the span of $\{v_1,v_2\}$.

Comment: $n=e_3$ makes no sense. What then is ${R}^{e_3}$?

Comment: I never wrote that nonsense in my post Nij. If you read the original post the asker is referring to $n$ as a vector who dot product with $x_0$ is 0.

Comment: The first four words in the question indicate that n is some positive integer, the dimension of the space.

Comment: I clarified that the vectors in referring to exist in $/mathbb{R}^4$ in case you were confused.

Comment: To be fair, in the question the OP is regarding $n$ as both a positive integer and a vector....

Comment: I am referring to $n$ as a vector. I thought that was clear, but apparently not for everyone. Anyway I still don't think the statement is true and I believe I have shown it to be false.

Comment: That's OK, maybe you can use more strict notations to show that it's a valid counter-example, e.g. `\mathbf{}` for vectors and `\begin{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}` notation for basis vectors maybe?

Comment: I am relatively new to Latex so I don't know all of the details yet. I am also writing these responses from my cell phone lol.  I'll say that my notation was the exact notation used in the original post (for whom my response was originally intended) and $n$ was primarily used as a vector so I followed suit.

Comment: You can press the "edit" button on my answer to see what I meant (and to learm a bit of MathJax too) ).

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not somehow obvious or "intuitively clear" for $n\ge 3$, as $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ spans $n-1$ dimensional subspace, but we are to show that $\mathbf{x}$ should be in a (maximum, in the case $\mathbf{v}_1\not\parallel\mathbf{v}_2$) $2$-dimensional subspace instead.
I'd note that $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ naturally follows from
$\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x}_0\cdot\mathbf{n}=0\\
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)\cdot\mathbf{n}=0
\end{cases}$ by addition.

---

More formal, let's see what we have got:
$$\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x}_0=a_1\mathbf{v}_1+a_2\mathbf{v}_2\\
\mathbf{x}_0\cdot\mathbf{n}=0\\
(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)\cdot\mathbf{n}=0
\end{cases}$$
Also, denoted $V=\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\}$, let's consider $V^\perp$ too.
Now, it's somehow obvious that for every $\mathbf{x}$ there are two vectors $\mathbf{y},\,\mathbf{z}$ such that $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{z}$, $\mathbf{y}\in V$, $\mathbf{z}\in V^\perp$.
So we're asked to show that if $\mathbf{x}=b_1\mathbf{v}_1+b_2\mathbf{v}_2+\mathbf{x}_\perp$ where $\mathbf{x}_\perp\in V^\perp$, then $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ $\implies$ $\mathbf{x}_\perp=\mathbf{0}$.
However, we can conclude $\mathbf{x}_\perp\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ at most, if $\mathbf{v}_1\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$, $\mathbf{v}_2\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$ (i.e. if $\mathbf{n}\in V^\perp$), that, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, would be equivalent to $\mathbf{x}_\perp=\mathbf{0}$ because $\dim V^\perp=1$, but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\ge 4$.

And in $\mathbb{R}^4$, [Matthew Holder's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3759598) gives a perfect counter-example, it reads:
$$
\mathbf{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\,
\mathbf{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\,
\mathbf{x}_0=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\,
\mathbf{n}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\,
\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
It's rather clear that $\mathbf{x}_0\cdot \mathbf{n}=0$,
$\,(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)\cdot \mathbf{n}=\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{n}=0$, but $\mathbf{x}$ can't be in $V=\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\}$ as every vector in $V$ have the form $(x,y,0,0)^T$ and thus the $4$th coordinate $0$, but $\mathbf{x}$'s $4$th coordinate is $1$ so it's not in $V$, counter-example is true, claim is false, QED.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already figured it out. Up to 3 dimensions you can exploit a geometric interpretation (that is not valid in higher dimensions): $x_0$ belongs to a plane and the inner (or dot) product of it with $n$ produces zero (a scalar). Then $n$ is perpendicular to the plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$. Since the dot product $x.n=x_0.n=0$ implies that $x$ is perpendicular to $n$, then $x$ belongs to the plane perpendicular to $n$ which is spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: Yeah, that's my intuition. But I'd like to prove it formally.

Comment: Not sure that it would make it shorter, but you can create a basis (not necessarily orthogonal) for the plane via  $e_i=v_i/|v_i|$ for $i=$1 and 2. Then $x_0=a\: e_1+ b \ e_2$, with $a,b$ constants and recall than $n$ is perpendicular to $e_i$ (dot product is zero). You can use "your intuition" and your derivation to make another construct similar for $x$ and prove that the dot product is zero. Ergo, $x$ is linear combination of the basis vectors $e_i$  and therefore spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.